# is it necessary to use Microsoft approach in every class for finding software maintainability?

Tags: testing, architecture, software-design

For finding software maintainability by using Microsoft approach,   where normally we have to use following method

MI = MAX(0, (171 — 5.2 * ln(HV) — 0.23 * CC — 16.2 * ln(LoC)) * 100 / 171),

Where,

HV – Halstead Volume,

CC – Cyclomatic Complexity;

LoC – lines of code.

In my program i have  few different type of classes .as example
For "finding area "**_**_problem
i have ----"circle", "triangle","quadrilateral", "abstract","choice" classes .

do i have to use the approach for every individual class for finding software maintainability ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples answer is no. This is only a heuristic formula created to assess code and drive code refactoring in order to achieving good maintainability. You can find many other interesting heuristics if you look for [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) (aka anti-patterns).

In the real world, you face challenges, like resource constraints (e.g. time, legacy, design options), which usually leads to decisions that create [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt). So, do not worry so much about strictly following these formulas. They are guidelines to help in making good decisions while designing your software architecture.